# Is there a way to get a range for numbers larger than int32?

Tags: powershell, foreach

I need to iterate over a small range in a very large number:

e.g between 99999999999999950 and 100000000000000000

I'm calling a function, passing in the lower and upper numbers as variables, but won't necessarily know what they are in advance, so I can't think of a way to reduce them and expand them inside the range/loop.

I'm able to use `[uint64]`, but it seems the range operator e.g. `$lower..$upper`only works on `int32`. It tries to convert anything larger to `int32` to generate the range.

```bsh
$lower = [uint64]99999999999999950
$upper = [uint64]100000000000000000

foreach ($i in $lower..$upper){
    #do something
}
```

The error is:

```
Cannot convert value "99999999999999950" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."
At line:4 char:16
+ foreach ($i in $lower..$upper){
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastIConvertible
```

Which makes sense I guess, as it's too large, but is there a way to do what I need in PowerShell? Is it not possible for the range operator to work on large numbers, or how can I get around this?

Comment: Instead of a `foreach`, try a `for` loop.

Comment: Just a tip, but not a fix, python has no limit to number size, and handles math exponentially faster than powershell. It's a very similar format too, just slightly different syntax. your code would be (replace semicolons with newlines) `lower = 99999999999999950; upper = 100000000000000000; for i in range(lower,upper):    do something` put a tab before "do something"

Comment: @RobertCotterman powershell also has the ability to store [arbitrarily large integers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an int64 or a decimal with a for loop.  I believe a "foreach ($i in 1..$someint)" gets converted to something like this anyway.

```
for ($i = 99999999999999950; $i -le 100000000000000000; $i++) {
  $i
}

for ($i = 99999999999999950d; $i -le 100000000000000000d; $i++) {
  $i
}
```

Interesting how the memory usage doesn't go up with a large foreach interval.

```
foreach ($i in 1..200000000) { sleep 1 }
```

And then in another window:

```
get-process powershell

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    621      38    82488      95356       1.09   2240  46 powershell
    674      36    61972      20680       1.77  10836  46 powershell
```

If you want to really slow down your computer to a crawl, do this.  I didn't wait for it to finish before closing the window.
 2.5 gigs working set memory.

```
 $a = 1..200000000
```

```
get-process powershell

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    572      37  3172532    2563624      33.19   2240  46 powershell
    613      37    62376      20944       2.28  10836  46 powershell
```

Answer (score 0):

The range operator produces a lot of objects. Probably that's why they avoid using that on 64-bit int. But there's a workaround that allows you to use `foreach` with big values, provided the range size doesn't exceed 32-bit ints

```
$lower = [uint64]99999999999999950L
$upper = [uint64]100000000000000000L
$diff = $upper - $lower # you may also set $diff as [int32]

foreach ($i in 0..$diff){
    $var = $lower + $i
    # do something with $var
}
```

or just convert to a `for` loop instead

Comment: Sorry, I edited your post instead of my own.  I undid it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell 5 or newer, you could implement an `IEnumerable` type whose enumerator just spits out consecutive `[bigint]` values:

```bsh
class BigIntRange : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    [bigint]$from
    [bigint]$to
    [bigint]$value

    BigIntRange([bigint]$from,[bigint]$to)
    {
        if($from -gt $to){
            throw [System.ArgumentException]::new("Range upper bound smaller than lower bound", 'to')
        }
        $this.to = $to
        $this.from = $from
    }

    [System.Collections.IEnumerator]
    GetEnumerator()
    {
        return [BigIntCounter]::new($this.from, $this.to)
    }
}

class BigIntCounter : System.Collections.IEnumerator
{
    [bigint]$from
    [bigint]$to
    [bigint]$value

    BigIntCounter([bigint]$from,[bigint]$to)
    {
        if($from -gt $to){
            throw [System.ArgumentException]::new("Range upper bound smaller than lower bound", 'to')
        }
        $this.to = $to
        $this.from = $from
        $this.Reset()
    }

    [object]
    get_Current()
    {
        if($this.value -lt $this.from -or $this.value -gt $this.to){
            throw [System.InvalidOperationException]::new("No valid current item")
        }
        return $this.value
    }

    [bool]
    MoveNext()
    {
        if($this.value -ge $this.to){
            return $false
        }

        $this.value += 1
        return $true
    }

    [void]
    Reset()
    {
        $this.value = $this.from - 1
    }
}
```

Then use like:

```bsh
$lower = [bigint]::Parse('99999999999999950')
$upper = [bigint]::Parse('100000000000000000')

foreach($i in [BigIntRange]::new($lower, $upper)){
    # do stuff with $i
}
```

Comment: Cool.  I'm surprised it doesn't use more memory.  Oh it's only 50 elements.

Comment: Each `[bigint]` is internally made up of an array of uint32's and a signing bit - the values in OP's sample range (ironically) all fit into 64 bit data structures :-P